# Accessing bind-at values from a snippet in Lift

Tags: scala, lift

I have a template that looks like this:

```
<lift:surround name="default" at="page-content">
  <lift:bind-at name="page-title">Home</lift:bind-at>
  ...
</lift:surround>
```

The default template looks like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title Prefix | </title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1><lift:bind name="page-title" /></h1>
    <div id="page-content">
      <lift:bind name="page-content" />
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to use a snippet to replace the `<title>` content with a string that combines "Title Prefix" and the value of `<lift:bind-at name="page-title">` (ie: "Home"). I want to contine to use that same value inside the `<h1>` in the `<body>`

How can I access a `bind-at` value from within a snippet that's used in the surrounding template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do what you are looking to do with `bind-at` directives, or at least, I haven't found a way. You should be able to use a snippet to accomplish something similar though.

For example, if you are using `SiteMap`, the following should be roughly equivalent.

```
class TitleSnippet {
  //Store the value in a requestVar
  private var titleVar:String = ""

  def first = {
    //Retrieve the title for the current Loc as defined in the Sitemap
    val locTitle = for (request <- S.request;
      loc <- request.location) yield loc.title

    //Retrieve the text portion of the tag, and append it to the sitemap title. 
    //If no sitemap title exists, just display the text
    "* *" #> { ns => 
      val myTitle = locTitle.map{ t => 
        "%s | %s".format(ns.text, t) 
      } openOr ns.text 
      titleVar = myTitle
      Text(myTitle)
    }
  }

  def title = {
    "* *" #> titleVar
  }
}
```

Then, in your template, all you'd have to do is say:

```
<title data-lift="TitleSnippet.first">Home</title>
```

So, if we had a page defined like this in the sitemap:

```
Menu("Sub Page 1") / "subpage"
```

If everything worked, you should see a title like: `<title>Home | Sub Page 1</title>` and if you need it elsewhere on the page, all you would have to do is: `<h1 data-lift="TitleSnippet.title"></h1>`.

If you need access from other snippets, you can also break out `titleVar` into a companion object and use a `RequestVar`.